# Timer Object in Python or anything like that

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I want to track time in python in order to rerun the model in 1 week of time. I could use:

```
  import threading
  def learn_model():
    #stuff goes here
  p = threading.Timer(604800, learn_model)
```

Will this repeat p after 1 week?

Comment: Is your program going to be on continuously for the intervening week?

Comment: I would find a different way to run your code at a certain time, a cron job or some windows equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for that code to run at all you need to add:

```
p.start()
```

So you have

```
import threading
def learn_model():
  #stuff goes here
p = threading.Timer(604800, learn_model)
p.start()
```

Then the code in learn_model will execute after a week. But, it will only run once.

Comment: This program needs to be running uninterrupted the entire time for it to work. If the computer gets rebooted or even if the console window is closed by accident, the program will stop and nothing will run. See Padraic's comment.

Comment: I will be running it on EC2 instance with tmux screen. Will there be same problem then?

Comment: That will help but really you're asking for trouble. I too recommend using something like cron for this.